How to find MIN() of sorted aggregates without using loops
I have a table that my daily script sends the findings to. It looks something like this:



product
issues_found
run_date




Alpha
2
2024-8-12


Alpha
5
2024-8-11


Alpha
3
2024-8-10


Alpha
0
2024-8-9


Alpha
1
2024-8-8


Alpha
5
2024-8-7


Beta
4
2024-8-12


Beta
3
2024-8-11



I want to find out the date when the current set of issues started for every product (i.e., the latest date when issues_found turned from 0 to non-zero), and add it to another column. So the table should become something like:



product
issues_found
run_date
issues_started




Alpha
2
2024-8-12
2024-8-10


Alpha
5
2024-8-11
2024-8-10


Alpha
3
2024-8-10
2024-8-10


Alpha
0
2024-8-9
2024-8-10


Alpha
1
2024-8-8
2024-8-10


Alpha
5
2024-8-7
2024-8-10


Beta
4
2024-8-12
2024-8-11


Beta
3
2024-8-11
2024-8-11



My approach is to iterate over date-sorted records for every product and break when 0 is encountered:
DECLARE found_date DATE;
FOR row in (SELECT * FROM my_table)
DO
  SET found_date = NULL;
  FOR historical_entry in (SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE product = row.product ORDER BY run_date DESC)
  DO
    IF historical_entry.issues_found <> 0 THEN
      SET found_date = historical_entry.run_date;
    ELSE
      BREAK;
    END IF;
  END FOR;
  UPDATE my_table SET issues_started = found_date where product = row.product;
END FOR;

It's a very procedural approach and although it works, it takes hours when run against hundreds of products and thousands of records. Is there a better approach than two nested loops? I tried using MIN(run_date) over aggregates of non-zero issues_found rows but couldn't quite get it right.

Your expected output does not make any sense.  Why is 2024-8-10 the issues_started date both before and after the date 2024-8-10 ?  Shouldn't it be filled on only one side?

@TimBiegeleisen, you are right, but the older dates don't matter to me. I only use the latest record, and will ignore the issues_started date if there are no issues today. I posted the question this way only to keep it simple.

Consider below approach
WITH issue_starts AS (
    SELECT
        product,
        run_date,
        issues_found,
        CASE
            WHEN issues_found <> 0 AND IFNULL(LAG(issues_found) OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY run_date), 0) = 0 
            THEN run_date
        END AS start_of_issues
    FROM your_table
), latest_issue_start AS (
    SELECT
        product,
        run_date,
        issues_found,
        MAX(start_of_issues) OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY run_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS issues_started
    FROM issue_starts
)
SELECT
    t.product,
    t.issues_found,
    t.run_date,
    l.issues_started
FROM your_table t
JOIN latest_issue_start l
ON t.product = l.product AND t.run_date = l.run_date
ORDER BY t.product, t.run_date DESC

if applied to sample data in your question - output is


Your output does not match what is contained in the OP above.

I know, based on my 9+ years experience here in SO I feel it is what OP needed :o)

@MikhailBerlyant, you're absolutely right. This is not what I asked (to keep the question simple), but this is what I needed. :)
Thank you so much. Many things in your answer went over my head, and I will surely read up on these. Meanwhile, is there an easy way to clear the issues_started for rows with 0 issues_found?

just add to final SELECT something like - IF(t.issues_found = 0, NULL, l.issues_started) AS issues_started

It worked perfectly. Thank you. You're a rockstar.
